# Do I need a visa for Spain (Schengen visa) if I already have a valid visa for Romania?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, romania

I am travelling to Spain next month, but I already have a valid multiple-entry visa for Romania. Will that exempt me from needing a Schengen visa? Or do I still need one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Romania is not part of the Schengen area. You need a Schengen visa for Spain even if you have a Romanian visa.